# How do you get an int++ to keep counting past 9?

Tags: objective-c

I'm relatively new to Objective-C and I'm trying to create a game.

I currently have a score counter as such:

```
-(void)score { 
    scorenumber++;
    scorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", scorenumber];
}
```

The problem I'm having is I can seem to get the score to keep counting past 9. every time it reaches 9 it then resets back to 0 instead of going onto 10 11 12 and so fourth.

How can I solve this? what I'm trying to accomplish is that everytime theres an intersect between coin and star it adds +1 to score and every time it passes through tunnel it adds +1 to score

heres the entire code.

Comment: There's something else going on here that you haven't shown us. `int` variables can hold values up to at least 2 billion.

Comment: @GregHewgill You mean, at least 32767.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Xcode and Objective-C don't run on 16 bit platforms.

Comment: Is the text area *wide* enough to show the left-most digit(s)? The right most digits repeats 0..9, so if only the last digit was shown..

Comment: Agreed, this should work. Is the label too narrow, so that it only shows the last character?

Comment: Also, this is not an Xcode question.

Comment: Definitely not an issue with this code, we will need to see more

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the UILabel (or whatever else displays your number)  isn't large enough to show more than one number. When it reaches 10, you only see the second digit, which is why you think it has been reset to 0.

Try making a longer scorelabel.

Answer (score 0):

If your design allows you to let the label have different width, you can use `sizeToFit` to give it enough width to display its text

```
-(void)score { 
    scorenumber++;
    scorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", scorenumber];
    [scorelabel sizeToFit]; // <------------
}
```